# Importing 2 types of variables from text file

Tags: arrays, file, text, import

I am not very fluent, simple question: when i have text file like this:

```
Name number
Name2  number2
```

How do i import it to Arrays, that I can operate on both of these? Numbers and names are separated by space. I have seen guides just to one type of variable, but what if i have two of them?

Comment: Depends on the language you are using, but the general concept is to parse the line through a filereader,read it line by line,and using delimiter to separate those whitespace (java default .hasNext already solve it),and store it into array. Then split the string array into 2 different type of array,that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pseudocode

```
while not eof:
    read name
    do sth with name
    read number
    do sth with number
```

In Java

```
String line;
String[] row;
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"))) {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        row = line.split("\\s+");
        names.add(row[0]);
        numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(row[1]));
    }
} catch (IOException e) {}
```

Comment: Would be thankful for any example of code doing that

Comment: @Myszsoda Which programming language do you fancy?

Comment: I would like to do it in Java.